# Spring ThreadPoolTaskScheduler vs ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

Tags: spring, task, scheduled-tasks, threadpoolexecutor, executor

It is mentioned in the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) that:

> `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` actually implements Spring's `TaskExecutor` interface as well, so that a single instance can be used for asynchronous execution as soon as possible as well as scheduled, and potentially recurring, executions.

So which are the scenarios where we would want to use `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` instance over `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` instance?

I am using currently using Spring XML. I am creating bean of `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` as follows:

```xml
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="1"/>
```

while bean of `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` instance can be created as

```xml
<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="10"/>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

- [`ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html) is a specialized class for executing tasks.
- [`ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.html) is a specialized class for scheduling tasks.

The sentence you quoted in the Spring documentation is only saying that you *can* use a scheduler to execute tasks, but that it is not its main purpose. A `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` provides fine-grained configuration over the thread pool through its [`corePoolSize`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html#setCorePoolSize-int-), [`maxPoolSize`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html#setMaxPoolSize-int-), [`keepAliveSeconds`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html#setKeepAliveSeconds-int-) and [`queueCapacity`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html#setQueueCapacity-int-) properties. A scheduler such as `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` does not provide such configuration.

As such, choosing between the two comes down the following question: do I need to execute or schedule execution of tasks?

Comment: Thanks, It really help me altos to understand between Executor and Scheduler.